# "crimes against humanity during the 1992-95 war"

Tags: reading-aloud, dates

*The amnesia about the continent’s capacity for slaughter will be broken in The Hague on Thursday, where judgment will be passed on Radovan Karadžić for charges of genocide and crimes against humanity **during the 1992-95** war in Bosnia and Herzegovina.*

I am not sure how to read aloud the date with the hyphen in the above sentence. Is it just "in the 1992 and 1995 war"? Or is it "until"? Or something else?

Comment: I would read it - *'...humanity during the nineteen ninety two ninety five war'

Comment: Oh, so it's a question on "reading aloud"? Then I would read it the same way as @MaulikV

Comment: I would read it as "nineteen ninety-two to ninety-five".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyphenated form **1992-95** used as an *adjective* is a sort of shorthand that makes the statement very curt.

"during the 1992-to-95 war".

If an author wanted to make it less curt and more amenable to being spoken aloud before a live audience, it could be rewritten:

**... crimes against humanity committed during the war in Bosnia and Herzegovina *between 1992 and 1995*.**

as CowperKettle wrote.